# Vue Ionic 6 fails to run on Vite SSR dev server

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework, vite

I am integrating Vite SSR to existing vue project. I copied vite configuration from SSR playground project and bumped ionic version to 6 because of dynamic loading issue from stencil.
After upgrading, it isn't compiling, showing this error.

```
12:03:15 AM [vite] Error when evaluating SSR module /src/components/ImportType.vue:
/data/Work/ssr-vue/node_modules/@ionic/core/components/ion-accordion.js:4
import { proxyCustomElement, HTMLElement, h, Host } from '@stencil/core/internal/client';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Here is my vite.config.js file

```
const vuePlugin = require('@vitejs/plugin-vue')
const vueJsx = require('@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx')
const virtualFile = '@virtual-file'
const virtualId = '\0' + virtualFile
const nestedVirtualFile = '@nested-virtual-file'
const nestedVirtualId = '\0' + nestedVirtualFile
/**
 * @type {import('vite').UserConfig}
 */
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    vuePlugin(),
    vueJsx(),
    {
      name: 'virtual',
      resolveId(id) {
        if (id === '@foo') {
          return id
        }
      },
      load(id) {
        if (id === '@foo') {
          return `export default { msg: 'hi' }`
        }
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'virtual-module',
      resolveId(id) {
        if (id === virtualFile) {
          return virtualId
        } else if (id === nestedVirtualFile) {
          return nestedVirtualId
        }
      },
      load(id) {
        if (id === virtualId) {
          return `export { msg } from "@nested-virtual-file";`
        } else if (id === nestedVirtualId) {
          return `export const msg = "[success] from conventional virtual file"`
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  ssr: {
    external: ["npm: @ionic/vue"]
  },
  build: {
    minify: false
  }
}
```

Please help me.